# Is there a minimum sample for custom op for TensorFlow Lite?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Obviously I cannot just take and copy paste my code for a custom operation I wrote for TensorFlow and use it in the Lite version

My code references things for the main code:

```
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/shape_inference.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h"

using namespace tensorflow;
```

and

```
Status MyAddGrad(const Scope& scope, const Operation& op,
                 const std::vector<Output>& grad_inputs,
                 std::Vector<Output>* grad_outputs){
```

I couldn't find anywhere a full (even minimum) sample for custom operations in TensorFlow Lite. Only which files I should modify in order to compile Lite to '.aar'

Answer (score 0):

The [Custom operators](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_custom) Guide page shows a canonical example of how you would implement a `Sin` custom op in TFLite.

You have to define `Prepare` and `Eval` functions for your op as shown [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_custom#defining_the_kernel_in_the_tensorflow_lite_runtime), and then let the OpResolver know using an `AddCustom` call.

Comment: Yes that is the link I've used, but I cannot figure out in an Android app where I should use the code

```
tflite::ops::builtin::BuiltinOpResolver builtins;
builtins.AddCustom("Sin", Register_SIN());
```

I've downloaded the sample image_classification and I've replaced the .tflite with my own and also my .arr I've created

Comment: [This is where the BuiltinOpResolver is created](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/java/src/main/native/builtin_ops_jni.cc#L25) (by default) for the TensorFlow Lite Java bindings. You can modify that code directly to add your custom op (you'll need to modify the BUILD file to add your sources), and then rebuild the .aar.